# CheckBox List in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkboxlist

I have a list of check boxes to display and I am using Twitter Bootstrap. My problem is that when I go to mobile site the text for the label covers the checkbox itself. Now, I have the following code and text is overlapping the checkbox. What can be wrong?

```
<ul class="nav nav-list"> <li><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="89" name="[14].Answer.SelectedAnswers">Biologie</label></li>
```

So, ex Biologie starts from the top of the checkbox and doesn't leave a space in between the box and start of the text.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have not closed the ul tag. coz i don't see it in your question. Or if you have try to put the entire link in a div with span3.

Comment: I have closed it. There are more li in my code so that's why you don't see the closing tag. I have found out that I needed to remove text-indent from the label css class of 'checkbox'. So it looks okay now.

Comment: @tulips There You go :)